# How do we seed questions in Stack Overflow for Teams?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams, api

We're considering a wider adoption of Stack Overflow for Teams or possibly Stack Overflow Enterprise. Are there any details and/or examples for seeding questions and answers (assuming via the API) from other systems of data?

A previous question asked if there are prebaked imports, but the answer was "talk with customer services". I'm hoping there's been some more thought as you've supported this product for a couple of years now.

CRM systems, like [Salesforce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salesforce.com), have had question and answer systems shoehorned into them, and we'd like to at least once import existing items (from data sources like CSV or other generic system).

If we have to roll our own, are there [DevOps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DevOps) friendly modules built to interact with the APIs for integration?

Comment: Did you mean [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342958/248731) prior question? It's helpful to give links.

Comment: Yeah that's the one thanks - I was coming off a demo of SO for teams to my org and was fielding follow ups at the time...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both Stack Overflow for Teams Business and Enterprise offer a write API for both asking and answering questions which can be used for seeding content.

We also offer data migration services for a fee depending on the data source.

Comment: It seems like some standard examples for folks who might have just vanilla data sources (like CSV's (and have DevOps resources like me)) might be a helpful article that will drive adoption and possibly assuage some concerns early on in selection. Obviously more complicated needs like retiring older systems will still go through your group as who wants to deal with that ;)